# ¿Cómo acceder a un archivo y sacar valores de los diccionarios desde python?

Tags: python-3.x

[image: La imagen muestra lo que se debe hacer en el codigo]

```
lista = [countries_data.readline()]
for elemntos in lista:
    if "languages" in elemntos:
        print(elemntos)
```

eso es lo que puse en mi código a lo que quiero acceder del archivo:

```
mi_lista = [
    
 {
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "capital": "Kabul",
        "languages": [
            "Pashto",
            "Uzbek",
            "Turkmen"
        ],
        "population": 27657145,
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg",
        "currency": "Afghan afghani"
    },
    {
        "name": "Åland Islands",
        "capital": "Mariehamn",
        "languages": [
            "Swedish"
        ],
        "population": 28875,
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg",
        "currency": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "name": "Albania",
        "capital": "Tirana",
        "languages": [
            "Albanian"
        ],
```

Comment: No entiendo exactamente donde está el diccionario si en una variable (aunque sea una archivo py aparte o tienes el contenido en un texto) en caso del primero y siguiendo la estructura de mi_lista tienes que recorrer milista mi_lista[i][clave] donde i es el numero de iteneración y clave es por ejemplo si lo sustituyes "name" obtendras el nombre de los paises

Comment: La pregunta es de baja calidad. Has pegado un enunciado como imagen, y además en inglés, seguidamente un código sin explicación y finalmente una estructura de datos con errores (pues no están cerrados los delimitadores) sin que se entienda tampoco de dónde salen esos datos. Revisa [Como elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Tal como está es posible que termine cerrada.